# Eloquent is setting a value to null

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

i'm having an error with Eloquent (and Many to Many relationship).
This is my code:

```
$user = new Users;
$rs = $user
    ->company()
    ->where('company_role.users_id', $request->session()->get('usrid'))
    ->where('code', $request->company)
    ->first();
```

The query that Eloquent perform is this one:

```
select `companies`.*, `company_role`.`users_id` as `pivot_users_id`, `company_role`.`companies_id` as `pivot_companies_id`, `company_role`.`role_name` as `pivot_role_name` from `companies` inner join `company_role` on `companies`.`id` = `company_role`.`companies_id` where `company_role`.`users_id` is null and `company_role`.`users_id` = 1 and `code` = 12345678901 limit 1)"
```

How is this possible? Do you guys have any idea?

This is my Users model:

```
class Users extends Model
{
    //table associated with model
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function company(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Companies','company_role')->withPivot('role_name');
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your schemas please :) Also, function `company()` suggests that there is only one company although it is N-N relationship. Are you sure that your foreign key is called `company_role` ? This doesn't make much sense. Those are only some hints, post your migration schemas to get better answer.

Comment: I don't have any migrations scheme. Yeah, i now that `company` suggest that there is only one company, i'll change it in the future. `company_role` isn't my foreign key, it's the name of the pivot table (it contains the user_id for the users table, the company_id for the company table and the role_id for the roles)

Comment: so in your pivot there is no `role_name` column? Change `withPivot('role_name');` to `withPivot('role_id');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, define the variables

```
$user_id = $request->session()->get('usrid');
$user = User::find($user_id);
```

Then, you need to find the user and the companies they are attached, and an individual company with the search params

```
$companies = $user->company()->get();

$company = $user->company()->where('code', $request->company)->first();
```

Comment: We've just posted something similar and you did what I did just 5 seconds ago :)

Answer (score 1):

## It was a rookie error

i just changed this:

```
    $rs = $user->company()->where('company_role.users_id',$request->session()->get('usrid'))->where('code',$request->company)->first();
```

into this:

```
        $rs = $user->find($request->session()->get('usrid'))->company()->where('piva',$request->company)->first();
```

and everything works as expected.

Thanks to everyone!